# Programmatic Method of Handling Matlab Dialog Windows

Tags: matlab, testing, matlab-gui

I have a rather large Matlab program that is GUI based. I am looking into creating automated tests for it, as the current way of checking for bugs before a release is simply using all its functionality like a user would.

I would rather not use a GUI testing program that just records clicks and what not, so I was thinking of adding testing code that would call the button callbacks directly. The problem that I have run into with this is that we have a lot of `warndlg` and `msgbox` popups, and I would like my tester code to be able to see these.

Is there any way for Matlab code to tell if a function it called created a `warndlg` or `msgbox`? If so, is there any way to click 'ok' on these popups?

In a similar vein, is it possible to handle popups that block code execution (using `uiwait` or an `inputdlg`)?

If it matters I didn't use GUIDE, and all the GUI elements are created programmatically

Answer (score 1):

Two ways. The first one is more elegant

- Let the functions return an extra variable and return the status of the function. For example, 1: success, 2: success with warning, 3: error...
- Create some global variables and make the function change them if a `warndlg` or `msbgbox` shows up. The main window would then check if the status of the global variable.

Comment: Thanks @MosGeo for the idea. Id rather not have to go and modify all my code to add extra return values though. Any idea how to know if pop-ups were created without adding extra return values?

Comment: Here is another way: don't use the default `warndlg` or `msbgbox`. Create your own functions that would trigger those two functions. In the process, they modify some global variable like I mentioned before. This way, you do not have to modify your, you just have to call the new functions instead of the original.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell if a warning dialog was created by looking for it's tag using the findobj function.  A warning dialog created using warndlg will have the tag "Msgbox_Warning Dialog".  So code like this would tell you if the warning dialog exists:

```
set(0,'ShowHiddenHandles', 'on')
h = findobj('Tag', 'Msgbox_Warning Dialog');
warn_exists = ~isempty(h)
set(0,'ShowHiddenHandles', 'off')
```

to close the warning dialog, you can call delete, like this:

```
delete(h)
```

For the message box, I would store the handle when you create a message box, then look at the children to find the buttons, then look at their callbacks.  You should be able to call the callbacks to simulate picking a button.